# Distribution of coefficient on the error correction term in ECM and VECM

Tags: estimators, t-distribution, vector-error-correction-model, ecm

According to statistic academic literature, the cointegration test on coefficient $\alpha$ of the error term included in ECM or VECM does not follow a standard distribution. My question is:

If so, why its significance is evaluated by t-statistic (which implicitly means that $\alpha$ follows the Student-$t$ distribution)? Or is there any misconception of mine?